How to resolve 'Error Merging File' using 1DM Download Manager on Android?
When downloading any video file over 10 MB download manager consistently fails when it reaches 100% with the error message "Error Merging File"?
Does anyone know how to resolve this issue or a workaround outside manually merging the files?
App Info: 1DM : browser and video download version 16.1
Device info is as follows : Samsung SM-G988U1 using Android 13 Tiramisu. There is plenty of space available on the internal drive and SD card, so storage capacity is not an issue.

That app is a commercial closed-source app. Have you checked the FAQ or contacted their support? https://www.apps2sd.info/idmp/faq
